# Cannot roll back subtransaction. No transaction or savepoint of that name was found

Tags: sql, t-sql, loops, transactions

i have a loop while in sql which do something as it

```
    begin tran one

    do some inserts in others tables

      --start loop
     begin tran two
      --do something
      begin try
--if something fail then a trigger does rollback and this return a error (and this goes to catch), then don't i need do the rollbak in catch? this could not be dissable because this is working on production
      --something finished ok 
      commit tran two
      end try
      begin catch
     rollback tran two
      end catch

    --finished loop
    commit


----------
```

i got this error

> Uncommittable transaction is detected at the end of the batch. The
>   transaction is rolled back.

```
begin tran one
begin tran two

rollback tran two
```

doing this code i get this:

> **Cannot roll back two. No transaction or savepoint of that name was found.**

I only want the subquery to rollback the second loop and continue with others records.

Comment: Review this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614942/how-can-i-ensure-that-nested-transactions-are-committed-independently-of-each-ot  Pay special attention to the links in the top answer.

Comment: Essentially, there is no such thing as nested transactions in SQL server.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Operator rollback rolls back all transaction, for roll back only second loop you you must use savepoints:

```
  begin tran one

-- do some inserts in others tables

  --start loop
  save tran two -- begin tran two

  --do something
  begin try
     update product set id = 1 --if something fail then a trigger does rollback and this return a error (and this goes to catch), then don't i need do the rollbak in catch? this could not be dissable because this is working on production

  --something finished ok 
  commit tran two
  end try
  begin catch

    rollback tran two
  end catch

--finished loop
commit
```

trigger example:

```
create table product (id int)
GO  
create trigger product_trigger on product for update
as
  set xact_abort off

  if (select count(*) from inserted i join product p on i.id=p.id)=0 begin 
    if (@@trancount>0) begin 
      /* rollback */ 
      raiserror('product does not exist', 16, 1) 
    end 
  end
```

Comment: well this is ok if i can rename the first transacion, but  as i said,  there is a trigger which does rollback, then i could not modify it because this is on production, and this does rollback only, this could work if this does rollback one, but this does rollback only , then this code does not work.

Comment: if(select count(*) from inserted i join product p on i.id=p.id)=0 begin if(@@trancount>0) begin rollback raiseerror('product does not exist') end end

Comment: I added an example of a trigger

Answer (score 5):

In my case, was my code was calling, thru an **EF DbContext** method, a SQL Server stored procedure, which contained a non-nested transaction.

Since, as @NotMe has already pointed-out, that "[there is no such as a nested transaction in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4615018/378115)", I began wondering whether my process was really transaction-nestingless.

Suspecting, that my DbContext had some guilt, I started checking on DbContext options, until **DbContext.Configuration.EnsureTransactionsForFunctionsAndCommands = True** caught my attention.

So, as soon as I changed it value to **True**, everything worked successfully.

```
MyDbContext.Configuration.EnsureTransactionsForFunctionsAndCommands = false;
```

What happened?

Well, in my opinion, EF's **ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction** method was managing its own outer transaction as a wrapper to my stored procedure's inner transaction, so, when my stored procedure's ROLLBACK TRAN was hit, there was no pending transaction when EF's COMMIT/ROLLBACK code was hit.

Oddly enough, while gathering some references on **EnsureTransactionsForFunctionsAndCommands** property, I found that this default behaviour is due to one of the worst (in my opinion) EF team's decision ever, since it collides diretly with every ROLLBACK TRAN inside a T-SQL script.

For further details on EF, check insightfull SO's QA at [EF6 wraps every single stored procedure call in its own transaction. How to prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991609/ef6-wraps-every-single-stored-procedure-call-in-its-own-transaction-how-to-prev)

Basically, everyone should check `@@trancount > 0` before issuing a **ROLLBACK** command, whether named or not, specially inside stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc1 AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN
    EXEC Proc2
    IF(@@trancount > 0)
        COMMIT TRAN
END

CREATE PROCEDURE Proc2 AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END
```

For better awareness about **Microsoft SQL Server**'s nested transactions, I would suggest reading the following article
[Be careful using ROLLBACK on nested transaction in SQL Server!](https://dev.to/hanewali/be-careful-using-rollback-on-nested-transaction-in-sql-server-2b5p)

Hope it helps someone :-)

Comment: I was really looking at the wrong direction until i found this answer. Thank you!

Comment: so what is the proper way to execute transaction if we have orm and stored proces having their own nested transanction? I'm having the same problem with my dapper/sql client mixed queries. depends on dapper for new query but all the old code still rely on traditional sql client and this error pops up when query takes too long and have butterfly effect on other query. @Julio

Comment: @phonemyatt, although I have never used Dapper, after reading your comment, I have just realized that have I could have given more insight about the root cause of this issue and how to overcome it, In order to fix it, I have just updated my answer. I would suggest that you read from "Basically..." on.