# EF6 wraps every single stored procedure call in its own transaction. How to prevent this?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, transactions

Profiled with SQL Server Profiler: EF 6 wraps every single stored procedure call with `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT TRAN`.

Is not it a breaking change?

Maybe it is not only a breaking change, but makes any transactional logic impossible in SPs as we *never* can rollback our transaction in the stored procedure using `ROLLBACK TRAN` (note: there are no nested transactions in SQL Server), so one rollback rollbacks to `@@TRANCOUNT` zero. As we were in a transaction because EF 6 we got "Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0." standard SQL Server error.

Please do not ask me why I want to call stored procedures. I have hundreds, and all of them are using `TRY ... COMMIT ... CATCH ROLLBACK` logic.

Any ideas how can I prevent EF 6 to do this?

Comment: What about using [`UseTransaction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.usetransaction(v=vs.113).aspx) and starting your own manually?

Comment: What about using ADO.Net directly if you want more control?

Comment: Note that in EF Core ExecuteSqlInterpolated/ExecuteSqlRaw  do not automatically start a transaction. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlraw?view=efcore-6.0

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is an overload of the `ExecuteSqlCommand` method that prevents this behavior:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, sql, parameters);
```

Comment: Thank, Max you are great :-). Interestingly EF gurus ignored this question for more than 2 months. (and ignored the fact that this is a breaking change)

Comment: Life saving information - have been searching for weeks! Thanks!

Comment: What aboutthte SqlQuery command that you must use to call a stored procedure that returns data?  That one seems to slam closed whatever Database.BeginTransaction call you open, and gives you no option to avoid it.

Answer (score 32):

In EF 6.1.2, a flag controls the behavior.  Setting **EnsureTransactionsForFunctionsAndCommands** to false will affect SPs that have been imported into an entity (these call ExecuteFunction() internally).

```
 using (SomeEf6Context ctx = NewContext())
 {
     ctx.Configuration.EnsureTransactionsForFunctionsAndCommands = false;
     // Call an imported SP
 }
```

The setting will not affect any SaveChanges() calls.

[MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.ensuretransactionsforfunctionsandcommands(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: It is important to stress that this fix requires an update to EF 6.1.2 or newer. I'd been running around wondering why I couldn't find the EnsureTransactionsForFunctionsAndCommands property for almost a week because I had been using EF 6.0.0.

Comment: You saved my life

Answer (score 1):

Just to contribute, I'm using Unity as DI, EF 6.1.3 and database first and I was getting the message: **"New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session"** when I called a procedure or a function mapped in my edmx file. The option **EnsureTransactionsForFunctionsAndCommands = false** fixed the problem.
The Max Zerbini's solution worked too, but I would've to use that way for each procedure call.

Answer (score 0):

As what crokusek said, you can set that flag to disable transactions for SPs.

If you are using any Dependency Injection (DI) library, you can set that like this(I am using Simple Injector):

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public Container ConfigureSimpleInjector(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var container = new Container();

        // Configure OWIN and Identity Framework
        ...

        // Configure persistence
        container.RegisterPerWebRequest<FakeDbContext>(() =>
        {
            var fakeDbContext = new FakeDbContext();
            fakeDbContext.Configuration.EnsureTransactionsForFunctionsAndCommands = false;
            return fakeDbContext;
        }

        // Register other services
        ...

        container.Verify();

        // For MVC
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));

        return container;
     }
}
```