# SQL Server stored procedure - newly inserted data does not show up right away

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I'm sure some changes been done yesterday by someone else.

The behavior of a stored procedure changed, the procedure copies data from some other tables to a `MainTable` one by one and also do some other processes.

```
insert into logTable("part 1 started", getdate())

insert into mainTable
   select * from table1 

insert into logTable("part 2 started", getdate())

insert into mainTable
   select * from table2

.......
.......

insert into logTable("complete", getdate())
```

Data inserted used to show up right away in the `MainTable`, and in the log table can see each process goes right after data inserted.

But now seems like all data in `MainTable`, and `logTable`, shows up only after final complete.

There is nothing changed in the procedure but I think

Is this kind of transaction setting?

How can I set it back?

Thanks

Comment: You can't set back to previous version until and unless its there within the TFS or backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it ,

this is because of the  New Entity Framework  EF6 i just updated.

it treat everything as  transaction .

could be change by:

[Stored Procedure without transaction in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481063/entity-framework-6-stored-procedure-without-transaction)