# Cannot perform a shrinkdatabase operation inside a user transaction. Terminate the transaction and reissue the statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-4

While executing the below mentioned query in C# using Entity Framework, an error occurs. This query can be successfully executed in SQL Server Management Studio. But it's not working when called from  C# code. Please, anyone help me.

```
var RunStoredProcedure1 = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("USE MDRFDataBase;  DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(N'MDRFDataBase' );  ");
```

Error:

> Cannot perform a shrink database operation inside a user transaction. Terminate the transaction and reissue the statement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481063/stored-procedure-without-transaction-in-entity-framework

Comment: Thank you now, it is working.Can you post this link to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this it is working for me.

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction,
                                   "EXEC procedurename");
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer, how does it shrink the database?