# Run SQL without transaction

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Is there a way how to execute SQL or stored procedure without creating additional transaction in entity framework ? There is solution for entity framework [Stored Procedure without transaction in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481063/stored-procedure-without-transaction-in-entity-framework) but it is not available for .net core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of [ExecuteSqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlcommand?view=efcore-2.1) in EF Core is different than the EF6:

> Note that this method does not start a transaction. To use this method with a transaction, first call [BeginTransaction(DatabaseFacade, IsolationLevel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.begintransaction?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions_BeginTransaction_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Infrastructure_DatabaseFacade_System_Data_IsolationLevel_) or [UseTransaction(DatabaseFacade, DbTransaction)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.usetransaction?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions_UseTransaction_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Infrastructure_DatabaseFacade_System_Data_Common_DbTransaction_).
>
> Note that the current [ExecutionStrategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.executionstrategy?view=efcore-2.1) is not used by this method since the SQL may not be idempotent and does not run in a transaction. An ExecutionStrategy can be used explicitly, making sure to also use a transaction if the SQL is not idempotent.

In other words, what are you asking is the default behavior in EF Core, so no action is needed.

Comment: Wow that is great, i always manage transaction myself in SQL Server. Thank you :-)