# With EF6 do I need to use COMMIT and ROLLBACK inside a Stored Procedure?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I am using EF to call stored procedures like this:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, parameters);
```

These procedures do multiple inserts and updates. I added, a TRY region and a COMMIT at the end of the TRY and a ROLLBACK (inside a CATCH) logic but this is giving me an error which I traced back to this:

[Stackoverflow Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991609/ef6-wraps-every-single-stored-procedure-call-in-its-own-transaction-how-to-prev)

If the case is that EF wraps the stored procedure calls then does this mean there is no reason to do that inside the stored procedure or should I leave the COMMIT and ROLLBACK in the SP and do this:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, sql, parameters);
```

Comment: In the end of the day, only you can tell whether or not you need transaction management in the stored procedure. We don't know what happens there.

Answer (score 3):

If possible, you should not handle the transaction in the stored procedures and go for something like this, with DbContexts relying on existing connection and transaction :

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var tran = conn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        using (var ctx1 = new DbContext(conn, false))
        {
            ctx1.Database.UseTransaction(tran);
            ctx1.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Exec YourStoredProc1");
            ctx1.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Exec YourStoredProc2");
        }

        using (var ctx2 = new DbContext(conn, false))
        {
            ctx2.Database.UseTransaction(tran);
            ctx2.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Exec YourStoredProc3");
        }
        tran.Commit();
    }
}
```

As the transaction is already provided, Entity Framework will not wrap yur calls in new transactions.
You can handle the rollback logic for errors with `try{}catch(){}`, of course, but also with any business code you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    //EF context
   using (TestDatabaseEntities contect = new TestDatabaseEntities())
    {
      //TODO:`enter code here`
    }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry but this does not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

The rollback will rollback all opening (active) transaction. Incase using EF, EF always auto create an root (outermost) transaction, so that the rollback inside a stored proc will rollback the transaction created by EF as well and it will cause error.
There is a way to get over, using Save point -> seee https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188378.aspx

I've applied the template save point for EF and it works well.