# Entity Framework calls a stored procedure in a transaction

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I have an understanding problem. We have the following code, to call a stored procedure with Entity Framework.

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext()) 
{
    using (var transaction = context.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)) 
    {
        var task = await context.DuplicateElementStartAsync(transaction, sessionId).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

...

public async Task<int> DuplicateElementStartAsync(DbContextTransaction transaction, string sessionId)
{
    int newTaskId;
    var mss = this.Database.Connection as SqlConnection;

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand()) 
    {
        cmd.Connection = mss;
        cmd.CommandText = "DUPLICATE_ELEMENT_START";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = ProgramEnvironment.StoredProcedureTimeout;
        cmd.Transaction = transaction.UnderlyingTransaction as SqlTransaction;

        var mparam0 = cmd.Parameters.Add("session", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        mparam0.Value = sessionId;
        mparam0.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        var mparam1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("new_task_id", SqlDbType.Int);
        mparam1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        if (mss.State != ConnectionState.Open) {
            await mss.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);;
        }

        await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        newTaskId = (int) mparam1.Value;

        mss.Close();
    }

    return newTaskId;
}
```

When calling a stored procedure, do I have to call `transaction.Commit()`, and if something goes wrong, `transaction.Rollback()`, or are these calls not necessary to a stored procedure?

I am not sure at the moment, I would be grateful for any hints.

Comment: You can always use a transaction with EF. However, if you choose not to, then EF will internally take care of it. I suggest you go through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions

Comment: If **you** created the `SqlTransaction` in your own C# code, then **yes**, you **must** call either `.Commit()` or `.Rollback()` to complete the transaction.

Comment: @marc_s: this means, in my code sample above, I have to add a **try/catch** and `.Commit()` and `.Rollback()`? This was my real question and I'm unsure.

Comment: Yes, exactly ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF6 wraps every single stored procedure call in its own transaction. How to prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991609/ef6-wraps-every-single-stored-procedure-call-in-its-own-transaction-how-to-prev)